# Converting string of exponent value to string of decimal value

Tags: vb.net

I want to convert string of exponent values (values are stored in data grid view continuously) to string of decimal values

```
    For Each waveform As AnalogWaveform(Of T) In waveforms

        scaledDataGridView.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(columnIndex).Value = scaledRecords(columnIndex - 1)(rowIndex - lastCount).ToString("E")
        columnIndex += 1
    Next

    If rowIndex Mod 100 = 0 Then
        Application.DoEvents()
    End If

Next
Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
TextBox1.Text = scaledDataGridView.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(columnIndex).Value.ToString("D")
```

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, please edit your question to give us an example of an exponent value and the decimal value you want from it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change this to:

```
TextBox1.Text = scaledDataGridView.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(columnIndex).Value.ToString("D")
```

To

```
Dim dec as Double = Convert.ToDouble(scaledDataGridView.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(columnIndex).Value)
TextBox1.Text = dec.ToString("G17")
```

The reason is because you need to convert back to a number before any formatting could be done.  In your case, it's trying to format a string with a format of D.

This will work up to about 17 places, otherwise it's different.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#GFormatString